# Prove that if $G$ is a finite group, then the index of $Z(G)$ cannot be prime.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

[This appears to be new to MSE.](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Finite%20group%2C%20%24G%24%2C%20prime%2C%20%24%5Cleft%5BG%3AZ%5Cleft(G%5Cright)%5Cright%5D%5Cne%5C%20p%24&p=1#)

I'm reading *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition),"* by Gallian.

This is Exercise 7.38 *ibid.* **Answers that use only the tools available in the textbook so far will be preferred.**

> Prove that if $G$ is a finite group, then the index of $Z(G)$ cannot be prime.

*Thoughts:*

What I had in mind first of all was to try the contrapositive:

> Let $G$ be a group. Then if $[G:Z(G)]=p$ for some prime $p$, then $G$ is infinite.

No progress worth sharing was made after a short while here.

Next, I considered when $G=Z(G)$; that is, when $G$ is abelian; with $G$ finite. Then $[G:Z(G)]=1$ is not prime. This does not seem helpful.

The section of the textbook *ibid.* this exercise is from is on "Cosets and Lagrange's Theorem". This gives me some indication that an argument at the "coset level/definition" of the index of a group would be most appropriate.

None of the previous exercises leap out at me as helpful.

Please help :)

Comment: I've got the feeling that this should be easy.

Comment: Show that when $[G:Z(G)]$ is prime the quotient $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic and conclude that $G$ must be abelian.